# How can I expand a Bootstrap 3 column to be the full page width when the page is printed?

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap-3

When a page in my application is printed, I'd like to hide the side navigation and expand the width of the main content to be a full 12 columns (I'm using Bootstrap 3).

Here's the current html/css.

```
<div class="row">
  <div class="col-md-3 side-navigation hidden-print">
    ...
  </div>
  <div class="col-md-9">
    ...
  </div>
</div>
```

What's the Bootstrap idiomatic way to expand the second column's width when printed?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There were at the moment of answering no helper classes in Bootstrap to do this.
When you want to accomplish such a thing, you can hide div's with css or
set the class of the second div with Javascript and change it from col-md-9 to col-md-12.
Or, see the answer with the 'print' class.

Answer (score 4):

It's possible, with additional css rules:

Add class **print-9** to your **col-sm-9** class.
Then add this to your css:

```
@media print {
    .print-9 { width: 100% }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

Expanding upon Andrey's answer. To account for offsets, like **col-offset-1**, you need to set the margin-left to 0.

```
@media print {
    .col-print-12 {width: 100%; margin-left:0px;}
}
```